# How to find this frequency?

Tags: real-analysis

The frequency $\omega(x)$ of a function $ x:=[0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$\omega(x):=\limsup_{T \to \infty}\frac \pi T \nu(x,T), $$  where $ \nu(x,T)$ stands for the number of zeros of $x(t)$, counting with their multipilicities, on $(0,T]$. What is the frequency of $x(t):=\sin(t)+\sin(\pi t) $?

Comment: Apply the "sum-to-product" identity for a sum of two sine functions.

Comment: @ RecklessReckoner : How to calculate $\omega(\sin (t) +\sin(\pi t))$?

Comment: @ RecklessReckoner : BTW, this is a question from a student math olympiad at Moscow State University.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$ f(x)=\sin(\pi x)+\sin(x) = 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi+1}{2}x\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi-1}{2}x\right)$$
there are about $\frac{\pi+1}{2\pi}T$ zeroes of $\sin\left(\frac{\pi+1}{2}x\right)$ and $\frac{\pi-1}{2\pi}T$ zeros of $\cos\left(\frac{\pi-1}{2}x\right)$ in $[0,T]$, hence the frequency of $f(x)$ is just $\pi$.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio : Thank you. Indeed, the relation $\nu( \sin(kt),T)=\frac {k} {\pi}T+O(1),\, T \to \infty,\, k \in \mathbb{R}, $ and the same relation for $\cos(kt)$ imply the frequency under consideration equals $\pi$. I think the definition of the frequency $\omega(x)$ should be adjusted because the frequency of $x(t)$ and a shifted  function $x(t)+a, a \in \mathbb{R}$ are expected to be equal. That was the reason to ask the question.  There are strong mathematicians with a large knowledge base in MathSE, so I have hoped to obtain the clarification of that place from them.